# Dell PowerEdge R410 memory clocked down after upgrade

Tags: dell-poweredge

We have 4x R410 servers and looking at upgrading RAM in all of those. We've started with one and can't figure out why the memory is being clocked down.

Old setup:

Dual CPU Intel Xeon L5520

Bank 1: 2x PC3-10660 4GB @ 1333 MHz

Bank 2: 2x PC3-10660 4GB @ 1333 MHz

Bank 3: 2x PC3-10660 4GB @ 1333 MHz

Bank 4: Empty

New setup:

Dual CPU Intel Xeon L5520

Bank 1: 2x PC3-10660 16GB @ 1066 MHz

Bank 2: 2x PC3-10660 16GB @ 1066 MHz

Bank 3: 2x PC3-10660 16GB @ 1066 MHz

Bank 4: Empty

The server documentation and the updated memory sheet from Dell states that in Optimizer mode, in dual-CPU scenario, the new setup should run at nominal 1333 MHz speed. The new RAM modules are: Kingston KTD-E313LV/16G, and provided by MrMemory as compatible upgrade. I believe these are correct dual-rank modules, as designated by 2Rx4 PC3L.

Would anyone be able to offer some advice or maybe would have an idea why these would be clocked-down?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the integrated memory controller on your CPU [does not support 1333MHz](http://ark.intel.com/products/40201/Intel-Xeon-Processor-L5520-8M-Cache-2_26-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI).  It only supports DDR3 800/1066.

Comment: So the old setup was always running at 1066 MHz... Should have checked the CPU specs really but for some reason I believed we were running the memory at full speed.
Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!